# how to make a textfield value available across different jframes in the same gui?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm creating a program that uses several different interacting menus to allow the user to access different parts of the system.  I'm using Netbeans to help with the coding.

At the moment I'm stuck on a task.

When a user logs into the system through a "login" form, the system validates the details, and that user is redirected to either a `user_details` or an `admin_menu` depending on the credentials.  That much works fine. From there, the user is able to access a form that allows them to update their details which are already saved in the database.

The only way I've found to limit the simple user to update their details is to ask them to login **again**, and from there retrieve their details so that they can be updated. This process is messy, but it works.

With that in mind how do I retrieve whatever was imputed in the textfield `Username` that is located in the jform Login from another jform (User_details), the `User_details` jform only opens once the login is successful (once that occurs login is discarded and `user_details` is opened).

### Here is part of my log in code :

```
String sql = "select * from user where Username =? and password=?";
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username.getText());
            pst.setString(2, password.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
                if ("manager@manage.com".equals(t.getText())) {
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                    close();
                    Admin_menu am = new Admin_menu();
                    am.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                    close();
                    User_details M = new User_details();
                    M.setVisible(true);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
```

---

how can i make the User_details Jform get what ever was imputed in the textfield username?

Comment: I encourage you to post the code specific to editing and persisting the form.  It shouldn't be the case that you have to re-login to persist data; once you're in, that shouldn't be an issue.  Please also provide relevant SQL queries too.

Comment: Sounds like you should start by reading up on the Singleton pattern. Google is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

If your program doesn't end(after the user has logged in once) u can save the entire information in a String array and just validate the array and redirect the user to the given form. eg.

```
//At login
String a[]=new String[2];
a[0]=username.getText();
a[1]=new String(pass.getPassword());
if(validate(a)){
   homescreen.setVisible(true);
}

//when user wishes to go to his homescreen
if(validate(a)){
   homescreen.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: 1.  What is `homescreen`, `pass`, and `validate`?  2.  `getPassword` is missing the parentheses.  I can't add them in until I can guarantee that it's a function call (as `getX` is usually an accessor call in Java).

Comment: it is just an example my friend basically a psuedocode and my bad for those parantheses